# SQLiteDatabase Order By Id Skips First Element

Tags: android, sqlite

Have a very strange issue with pulling data from SQLite Database on Android. Here is my method that takes all the entries from the table `entries` and iterates them through the loop, putting them in the list view.

It works fine until I wanted to change this line

`Cursor c = readableDatabase.rawQuery("select * from entries", null);`

to this one:

`Cursor c = readableDatabase.rawQuery("select * from entries order by ID DESC", null);`

So after the change I don't see the first element. Not sure what is going there. Here is the source code of that method.

```
EntryHelper entryHelper = new EntryHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = entryHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // NOTE: needs to be changed to order by ID...
        // 
        Cursor c = readableDatabase.rawQuery("select * from entries", null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        ArrayList productsList = new ArrayList();
        ProductsArrayAdapter productsArrayAdapter = new ProductsArrayAdapter(this, productsList);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Integer entryIdIndex       = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Schema.Entry.ID);
            Integer entryBarcodeIndex =  c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Schema.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_BARCODE);
            Integer entryQuantityIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Schema.Entry.COLUMN_NAME_QUANTITY);

            Integer entryId      = c.getInt(entryIdIndex);
            String entryBarcode  = c.getString(entryBarcodeIndex);
            String entryQuantity = c.getString(entryQuantityIndex);

            Product lineItemProduct = new Product(entryId, entryBarcode, entryQuantity);
            productsList.add(lineItemProduct);

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, lineItemProduct.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        productsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.productsList);
        productsListView.setAdapter(productsArrayAdapter);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: remove moveToFirst() method then it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
    c.moveToFirst();

    // other code

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
```

Your skipping the first element, `moveToFirst` puts your cursor at the first position, then your while moves one more position to the second position.

Either remove the `moveToFirst()` (you aren't checking the return type or doing anything with this anyway). Or change your `while` loop to a `do while` but this assumes you always have at least 1 result. I recommend removing `c.moveToFirst`.